# Private RSA vs Openssh key on Cygwin

Tags: rsa, openssh

When I generate a key with Cygwin I get a:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

but I need a:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

(2048)

I use  the command:

```
>ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

How do I generate good format key or how do I convert an openssh key into RSA key?

Comment: I found this: and works for me:

ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 2048